# Why my fitting distribution in R is throwing out errors?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution, fitdistrplus

Here is a sample code where i am trying to fit multiple distribution. Can someone please look into the error and run the code to its entirety? Thanks

```
# Step 1: Load required libraries
library(ismev)
library(tidyverse)
library(fitdistrplus)

# Step 2: Read and preprocess the streamflow data
streamflow <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), 
                            to = as.Date("2020-12-31"), 
                            by = "day"), 
                            value = runif(14976,1,500))

# Step 3: Calculate annual maximum flows
annual_max <- aggregate(streamflow$value, by = list(year = format(streamflow$date, "%Y")), FUN = max)

# Step 4: Fit multiple probability distributions to the annual maximum flows
distributions <- c("norm", "logis", "gev")  # Specify the distributions to be fitted
fit_results <- fitdist(annual_max$x, distributions)

# Step 5: Calculate return periods and associated flow values for each distribution
return_periods <- c(2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100)  # Specify desired return periods in years

# Loop through each distribution and calculate return flows
results <- data.frame(Return_Period = return_periods)
for (i in 1:length(distributions)) {
  return_flows <- qfunc(return_periods, distname = distributions[i], distr = fit_results[[i]])
  results[, paste(distributions[i], "Flow_Value", sep = "_")] <- return_flows
}
```

**Error point**
at `fit_results` it throws the following error

```
fit_results <- fitdist(annual_max$x, distributions)
Error in exists(ddistname, mode = "function") : 
  first argument has length > 1
```

Comment: To debug problems like that, my advice is to cut down the code to just enough to show the error you're running into. Also, in order to make headway, can you get it to run for just one distribution? If you're trying to get help from others, it would be helpful to post a small subset of the data, enough to replicate the error. That's all my general advice, more specifically in this case I wonder if `fitdist` only wants one distribution at a time -- something to check.

Comment: All good suggestions- thanks . I normally don't do it but pasted everything here to see if someone is able to run the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**, `fitdistrplus::fitdist` isn't vectorized, you need `lapply`, **2.**, There does not appear to be a `"gev" distribution available. I have not looked at the rest.

```
lapply(distributions, \(d) {
  tryCatch(fitdistrplus::fitdist(annual_max$x, d), error=\(e) NA)
})
# [[1]]
# Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#        estimate Std. Error
# mean 498.642567  0.2677010
# sd     1.714123  0.1892929
# 
# [[2]]
# Fitting of the distribution ' logis ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#             estimate Std. Error
# location 498.9166249  0.1784073
# scale      0.6861103  0.0924656
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
```

Comment: Yes, the `gev` is not there. the `lapply` worked. now its complaining about the `qfunc` during the `for loop`.  the `qfunc` is a basic `R` function not sure why its not finding

Comment: @Hydro Disagree, `qfunc` isn't base R. Check  with`?qfunc` from where or which package it is.